# Ajax loade View can't load javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I'm trying to load some views using ajax, and they are loading OK.

But the scripts they have, are not being loaded on the specific section. Why?

View code:

```
@model INTREPWEB.Models.BoardingViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";

    if (IsAjax)
    {
        Layout = null;
    }
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Partial("CreateEdit")
}
@section Scripts{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/intrep-datetime.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are loading just a content like a plain text. Try to parse loaded content and invoke all your script references with [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

**EDIT**

As an alternative can be used:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'script'
});
```

Comment: Can you explain how do I do that, please?

Comment: In the receiving data callback you can check with Regex response to find all `<script>` tags. Get the links of the `*.js` files and call `$.getScript("script_src.js")`. This will load script and invoke it. After that you can use it.

Comment: Or as an option you can just return the list of `*.js` files which should be loaded and load it.